# ¿Mostrar palabras repetidas en diccionario?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una función donde se recibe una frase y esta debe ser procesada y retornar un diccionario con las palabras repetidas, siendo la llave la palabra y el valor, la cantidad de veces que se repite.

Por ejemplo esta frase:

> Depurar código es dos veces más difícil que escribir código, por lo tanto, si escribes el código tan inteligentemente como te sea posible, por definición
> no serás lo suficientemente inteligente como para depurarlo

y se debe retornar un diccionario así

```
{'código': 3, 'por': 2, 'lo': 2,'como': 2}
```

tengo el siguiente codigo pero el diccionario muestra las palabras que no estan repetidas y con la palabra codigo la muestra dos veces, primero con un valor 2 y luego con un valor 1 y necesito que me ponga el valor como 3 una vez.

```
frase_celebre_programacion=str()

def procesar_frase(frase_celebre_programacion)->list:
 palabras=frase_celebre_programacion.split()
 cant_palabras=[]

 for x in palabras:
  cant_palabras.append(palabras.count(x))

 lista_palabras=list(zip(palabras,cant_palabras))
 diccionario=dict(lista_palabras)

 return diccionario

print(procesar_frase('Depurar código es dos veces más difícil que escribir código, por lo tanto, si escribes el código tan inteligentemente como te sea posible, por definición no serás lo suficientemente inteligente como para depurarlo'))
```

Además me piden utilizar la función map para procesar la frase y generar el diccionario pero no se como realizar esto, soy nuevo en este lenguaje.

Comment: perdon, se me olvido comentar que cuando quito la coma despues de la primera palabra 'codigo', ahí si me muestra en el diccionario {'codigo':3} pero si le dejo la coma me pone como dije anteriormente. Ya cambié el titulo.

Comment: lo siento ya lo entendí, pensé que te referías a otra cosa, ya tengo la respuesta, ahora la publico

Answer (score 0):

Una solución fácil es hacer una expresión regular con el modulo `re` y usar su método `split()` para poder separar una cadena según esa expresión regular.

```
from pprint import pprint #esto es para que la salida se vea bonita
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\s|,")


def procesar_frase(frase_celebre_programacion)->list:
 palabras=regex.split(frase_celebre_programacion)
 palabras = [p.lower() for p in palabras if p!=""] #verifcamos que no sea vacio
 cant_palabras = {} #aqui se almacenara el resultado

    for palabra in palabras:
        if palabra not in cant_palabras:
            cant_palabras[palabra] = 1 #creamos la clave con el valor 1
        else:
            cant_palabras[palabra] +=1 #sumamo1
    #obtenemos las repetidas
    repetidas = {k:v for k,v in cant_palabras.items() if v !=1 }
    return repetidas

frase = 'Depurar código es dos veces más difícil que escribir código, por lo tanto, si escribes el código tan inteligentemente como te sea posible, por definición no serás lo suficientemente inteligente como para depurarlo'

pprint(procesar_frase(frase))
```

La expresion regular indica que debe de coincidir en caso haya un espacio `\s` o una coma `,`, al usar `split()` le indicamos que separe la cadena en base a eso.

**resultado**

```
{'como': 2, 'código': 2, 'lo': 2, 'por': 2}
```

La solución de @CandidMoe es la mas optima, puesto que utiliza `itertools` y crea el diccionario y añade los elementos en la iteración usando la sintaxis de comprensión de diccionario

Comment: El OP pide las palabras repetidas.

Comment: Haaa.. lo siento, ahora edito la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Solución usando expresiones regulares e itertools:

```
import re
import itertools

def procesar_frase(texto):
    patron = re.compile("(\w+)")
    contadores = {k: len(list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(patron.findall(texto)))}
    return {k: g for k, g in contadores.items() if g > 1}
```

El patrón `(\w+)` reconoce y captura palabras (combinaciones de letras y números). Usando este patrón con `findall` obtenemos la lista de todas las palabras en texto.

Usando `sorted` ordenamos la lista y con `groupby` la dividimos en grupos de palabras iguales.

`groupby` es un generador que devuelve la palabra (`k`) y otro generador (`g`) que devuelve la lista con todas las ocurrencias de esa palabras. Con el generador obtenemos una lista y `len` nos dice cuantas veces se repite la palabra.

A esta alturas tenemos una palabra y las veces que aparece. Con eso vamos a crear un diccionario usando *comprensión de diccionarios*, para lo cual tienes que dar tanto la llave (`k`) como el valor (`v`) separados por dos puntos (`:`):

```
{k: v for k,v in algun_generador()}
```

En el caso general, `algun_generador` devuelve tuplas de valores que son asignados a `k` y `v`. El resultado final es un diccionario.

Como piden sólo las palabras repetidas, recorremos el diccionario extrayendo aquellos pares (palabra, veces) de las palabras repetidas. Con eso armamos y devolvemos un diccionario usando nuevamente comprensión de diccionarios.

**Demo**

```
from pprint import pprint

texto = "Depurar código es dos veces más difícil que escribir código, por lo tanto, si escribes el código tan inteligentemente como te sea posible, por definición no serás lo suficientemente inteligente como para depurarlo"
pprint(procesar_frase(texto))
```

produce

```
{'como': 2, 'código': 3, 'lo': 2, 'por': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por el funcionamiento de split. Si no le das un argumento va a separar caracteres en cada espacio. Nosotros reconocemos que los signos de puntuacion no son parte de las palabras, pero con una computadora tienes que ser muy explicito.

**[Split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)**:
Si no se especifica sep o es **None**, se aplica un algoritmo de división diferente: las ejecuciones de espacios en blanco consecutivos se consideran un solo separador y el resultado no contendrá cadenas vacías al principio o al final si la cadena tiene espacios en blanco iniciales o finales.

Nosotros reconocemos que los signos de puntuacion no son parte de las palabras, pero con una computadora tienes que ser muy explicito.

```
def procesar_frase(frase):
  def procesar_palabra(palabra)->str:
    return palabra.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').lower()
  return {x:palabras.count(x) for x in [procesar_palabra(p) for p in frase.split()]}

frase = 'Depurar código es dos veces más difícil que escribir código, por lo tanto, si escribes el código tan inteligentemente como te sea posible, por definición no serás lo suficientemente inteligente como para depurarlo'

procesar_frase(frase)
```

Regresa

```
{'como': 2,
 'código': 2,
 •
 •
 •
 'te': 1,
 'veces': 1}
```